# Passing Order Value to conversion code in Success page

Tags: bigcartel

I'm implementing Google Dynamic Remarketing code for 'success' page and I would like to pass order data to tracking script -

Is it doable? I don't see any Order variables in documentation. Would shopify order variables work?

Script I need to populate and pass -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var google_tag_params = {
ecomm_prodid: [PRODUCT IDs],
ecomm_pagetype: 'purchase',
ecomm_totalvalue: ORDER TOTAL
};
</script>
```

Script I use in Shopify Order Success -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var google_tag_params = {
{% if order.line_items.size > 1 %}
ecomm_prodid: [{% for line_item in order.line_items %}'{{line_item.product.product.id }}'{% if forloop.last != true %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}],
{% elsif order.line_items.size == 1 %}
ecomm_prodid: [{% for line_item in order.line_items %}'{{line_item.product.product.id }}'{% endfor %}],
{% else %}
ecomm_prodid: '',
{% endif %}
ecomm_pagetype: 'purchase',
ecomm_totalvalue: {{ cart.total }}
};
</script>
```

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but at the moment there's no way to pass any kind of order details to the Success page - unfortunately this type of code isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar challenge, given the constraints in Big Cartel, I dropped in a tracking script for conversions on the cart if the cart isn't empty. It was better than nothing.

```
{%if page.permalink == 'cart' %}
{% if cart.items != blank %} 
<script></script>
{%endif%} 
 {%endif%}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for Product id and total value in confirmation page of shopify 
you can use below code.

```html
<!-- google dynamic remarketing tag for thank-you page -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     var google_tag_params = {
           ecomm_prodid: [{% for line_item in order.line_items %} 'shopify_US_{{line_item.product.id}}_{{line_item.variant.id}}', {% endfor %}],
           ecomm_pagetype: 'purchase',
           ecomm_totalvalue: {{ subtotal_price | money_without_currency | remove: ","}}
        };
</script>
```

To get complete instruction follow this link http://www.notesonclick.com/blog/dynamic-remarketing-code-for-shopify/